# Is this the correct way to temporary add a property to django.conf.settings?

Tags: python, django

**Context**:

I am performing this in the context of my unittests.

**Goal:**

I want to add a property dynamically to the django settings like so:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.__dict__['USE_SSL'] = True
```

Is this correct or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
settings.USE_SSL = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.4 will have a way to [override settings in tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#overriding-settings).